# Do we not need to create actual nodes while creating a linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I'm studying linked lists from [this article.](http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)

The writer of the tutorial never creates actual nodes, but only pointer variables of type node, as you can see with the following code...

```
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;
```

and then he allocates space for them in the heap...

```
head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

why doesn't he ever create actual nodes? code for which should look something like this...

```
struct node head;
struct node second;
struct node third;
```

If my knowledge is right (correct me if I'm wrong). Simply declaring the pointer variable doesn't create the actual variable(node in case of linked lists), and hence cannot be dereferenced like the writer of the tutorial in the article using the code

```
head->data = 1;
```

I mean, if that works, then why doesn't this work?

```
int *a;
a=5;
printf("%d",*a);
```

Obviously, the above code doesn't output 5.

Which means that another variable needs to be created, and then it needs to be stated that the address of the variable is stored in a pointer variable, only then it can be dereferenced...like the following code...

```
int *a;
int b=5;
a=&b;
printf("%d",*a);
```

This outputs 5.

So how does the author gets away with not creating the nodes? He simply creates the pointer variables and then simply dereferences them....

Comment: `struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node))` definitely 'creates' it.

Comment: The whole point about pointers (and not just nodes) is that you can't safely prepend new element if your head node is pinned on the stack.

Comment: Well, you try taking out the malloc's and see how far you get.  Those are the nodes.  You ought to look up what malloc does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes are in the heap, that's what `malloc` is for.

To use code without linked list to explain, it's similar to:

```
int *a = NULL;
a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 5;
printf("%d",*a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure pointers are created so that they can refer to address.Since normal structure variables can't store the address, this syntax is wrong.

    `struct node head;
    struct node second;
    struct node third;`